# Showing parametrization of a screw-drive graph has a continuous inverse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, solution-verification

By a screw-drive graph I mean the set $$S=\{(R\cos t,R\sin t, at):t\in(0,\infty)\}$$

The function $g(t):(0,\infty)\to S$, such that $g(t)=(R\cos t,R\sin t,at)$ is a continuous bijection. I'm trying to show that $g(t)$ has a continuous inverse. I was wondering if the following idea might work. Let $M>0$, and $0<L<M$. The function $$g:[L,M]\to S$$

is a continuous bijection for every $L$ and $M$. As $[L,M]$ is compact, we have that $$g^{-1}:S\to[L,M]$$

is continuous. This also means $$g^{-1}:S\to(0,\infty)$$

has to be continuous. Correct?

Comment: Err... Can't you just say $g^{-1}(x,y,z) = z/a$?

Comment: "Helix" is the usual term for this kind of shape.

Comment: @preferred_anon how does that show the inverse is continuous?

Comment: @variations I don't understand your question. The function I wrote down is obviously continuous, and it's the inverse of your function $g$.